# Change format data using concat and replace mysql

Tags: mysql, replace, concatenation

I have an issue with my data. I have more than thousand data. All of this data I got from client. My problem is the date format from client is (dd.mm.yyy). I want change it into the normal date format. Is it possible to use REPLACE and CONCAT?

Comment: Use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function with proper parsing pattern:
```SELECT STR_TO_DATE(data_from_client, '%d.%m.%Y'), ...```

PS. What is `yyy` (3 chars) pattern?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `substring` and `concat` them to your desired format. Something like this for a normal MySQL Date Format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('05.04.2021', 7, 4), '-', SUBSTRING('05.04.2021', 1, 2), '-', SUBSTRING('05.04.2021', 4, 2)); -- 2021-05-04;
```

Here is the link in using
[MySQL Substring](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/func_mysql_substring.asp).